# Python: -bash: scrapy: command not found on Mac OS

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]

scrpay is in PATH
[image]

So why command is not found..
How to solve it?

---

when use 'which python':

`userdeMacBook-Pro:~ cdn$ which python`

`/usr/local/bin/python`

---

when use ls -l[image]

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin/scrapy` an executable file?  I'm not familiar with that file lister interface, but the icon looks like it might be just a plain file?

Comment: btw, posting the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/scrapy` would have been a lot more helpful than those screen shots.

Comment: @John Gordon Yes, it is an executable file.

Comment: Just because a symlink exists doesn't mean that the actual file is really  there